# E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'TextToFloat'

Tags: delphi

My code:

```
function  Str2Dbl(const str: string; var v: double): boolean;
var
  dp: integer;
  cstr: string;
  xv: extended;
begin
  if FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator <> '.' then
  begin
    dp := pos('.', str);
    if dp <> 0 then
    begin
      cstr := str;
      cstr[dp] := FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
    end
    else
      cstr := str;
  end
  else
    cstr := str;
  if cstr <> '' then
    result := TextToFloat(@cstr[1], xv, fvExtended, FormatSettings)
  else
    result := false;
  if result then
    v := xv;
end;
```

In Delphi 10.2 it gives an error:

```
[dcc32 Error] commutil.pas(1005): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'TextToFloat'
      System.SysUtils.pas(18332): Related method: function TextToFloat(PWideChar; var; TFloatValue; const TFormatSettings): Boolean;
      System.SysUtils.pas(18515): Related method: function TextToFloat(PAnsiChar; var; TFloatValue; const TFormatSettings): Boolean;
```

I do not understand how to fix this error!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because `@cstr[1]` has type `Pointer` and the overload resolution does not know which overload (`PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar`) you want.

In any case, using `@cstr[1]` is wrong in general, and will fail with a runtime error if `cstr` is empty. Use `PChar(cstr)` instead. This will also allow the overload resolution to work.

I appreciate that you test whether or not `cstr` is empty, but that test is not necessary if you use the magic of the `PChar(...)` cast. Even when the string is empty, `PChar(...)` gives a valid pointer to a null-terminated character array.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Mixing_Delphi_Strings_and_Null-Terminated_Strings) is worth consulting on this subject. The key statement is:

> `PChar(S)` always returns a pointer to a memory block; if `S` is empty, a pointer to `#0` is returned.

So, you will be able to replace:

```
if cstr <> '' then
  result := TextToFloat(@cstr[1], xv, fvExtended, FormatSettings)
else
  result := false;
```

which did not compile anyway, with:

```
result := TextToFloat(PChar(cstr), xv, fvExtended, FormatSettings)
```

which does compile and avoids that `if` statement boiler-plate.

**Aside**

I initially expected that enabling [typed address operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)#Type-checked_Pointers) with `{$T+}` would make `@cstr[1]` be a typed pointer and help the overload resolution. However, that is not the case. It was surprising to me that this program compiles:

```
{$T+}

var
  PA: PAnsiChar;
  PW: PWideChar;
  s: string;

begin
  PA := @s[1];
  PW := @s[1];
end.
```

The linked [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)#Type-checked_Pointers) says:

> When `@` is applied to a variable reference in the `{$T+}` state, the type of the result is `^T`, where `T` is compatible only with pointers to the type of the variable.

This seems to be contradicted by